# How to Compute fields on the fly

Tags: 7, ajax, entities

I have content type having fields as follows.

first

second

third

Sum1 (first + second +third) - computed filed

xxxx

yyyy

zzzz

Sum2 (xxxx+yyyy+zzzz) - computed field

Grand Total (sum1 + sum2) - computed field

I could achieve this by using **computed field** module. When I save node, I could able to find sums and Grand Total.

My problem is client wants to see  **sum1** filed in edit/create form and also wants to update sum1/sum2/Grand Total fields on the fly (dynamically).
There are couple of content types having the same requirement.

Before start to write a custom module, I would like to know alternates for this.Any suggestions?

Comment: When you say your client wants to update the sum fields dynamically, how is that even logically/mathematically plausible?  Or, are you asking that after your client modifies any of the first, second, or third fields that the sum fields should automatically update?

Comment: @Jimajamma I mean, whenever client enter/modify the values of first, second,or third fields the sum of these should automatically update 'total' filed.But here my problem is, if I use computed filed (to compute first second third) we can't see that filed in add/edit node form.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like cashier functionality. There has been some effort for D6, see [Drupal POS (Point of Sales) System](http://www.appnovation.com/blog/drupal-pos-point-sales-system). I haven't used this.

Ideally, this would be done with JavaScript (I have once done it for a non-Drupal system).

A cheap workaround would be the [Save & Edit](https://drupal.org/project/save_edit) module, where you just save the node and continue editing it, effectively updating the calculations. On demand, not automatically.

A smoother workaround would be updating (on demand) the form with ajax. [Ajax](https://drupal.org/project/ajax) module  has no D7 version, but in the issue queue is mentioned this sandbox project which supposedly can ajaxify the node edit form:
[Asaf (ajax submit for any form)](https://drupal.org/project/asaf).

You need one extra module for actually displaying Computed field on node *edit* form: [Field extra widgets](https://drupal.org/project/field_extrawidgets). Select the widget "read only".

Comment: Thanks Kari Kääriäinen, I'm going to work around your suggestions. Here my problem is If I use computed filed I can't see the filed in node form. I can see that field value at node output only.

Comment: You're right. There is a module for that ;) Answer edited.

Comment: Kari Kääriäinen - As you said I've just installed and tried that for computed filed (by selecting widget type Read only). it's showing up in edit form. but not in add form.  thanks for the idea:)

Comment: Oh no. Giving the field a default value would be the next logical step, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Kari Kääriäinen - Your modules helped me to solve my problem, by using computed field, field_extrawidgets, & save_edit modules. Ofcourse my way is not the exact solution for my question but client agreed to this :)